# Java EE CDI Manual Injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, reflection, cdi

I have one class named Class1. I don’t know what are the fields of such class neither but I do know
that there are fields in such class that use the annotation @Inject, witch means that
such fields need to have Object instances injected. What I do know is that the class has a Default Controller. I use
such controller to instantiate the class via newInstance method:

```
Object class1Object = Class.forName("Class1").newInstance();
```

The problem is that, The dependencies of the “Class1” are not being injected to the object instance fields and I understand that Its completely normal as I’m instantiating the class manually. I need to get that dependencies injected, so, I need a magic method to do so:

```
CDI.injectAllDependencies(class1Object);
```

Any ideas?
Please do not expect me to stop instantiating the class manually. My situation requires such approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. this might be an option if it works as it seems to. It instantiates the "Class1" class and inject all its dependencies. Am I right?

Comment: Is there a way of registering it programatically and not by the beans.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't recommend it, you can get all the fields annotated with @Inject by using reflection:

```
for (Field field : Class.forName("Class1").getFields() ) {
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Inject.class)) {
        //do all your nasty stuff here
    }
}
```

If you then want to get an instance of the field's type from CDI you can ask the BeanManager for it. Have a look at http://dominikdorn.com/2010/04/cdi-weld-manual-bean-lookup. After you have the instance you can use reflection to set the field to the instance as described in the Field API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)